# How to specify build options for docker-compose build stage?

Tags: docker, build, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-build

I have a main **docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  recognizer:  
    container_name: recognizer
    build: ./recognizer
    hostname: recognizer
    restart: always   
    ports:
      - 8084:8084
    network_mode: "host"
```

I have a folder **recognizer** with **Dockerfile** and **docker-compose.yml**:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN mkdir -p /app/

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN chmod 777 /app/gradlew

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat-traditional

RUN nc -w 2 -v localhost 5432 </dev/null; status=$?; exit $status;

RUN ./gradlew build

CMD ["./gradlew", "run"]

EXPOSE 8084
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
recognizer:
  build:
    context: .
  ports:
    - "8084:8084"
```

My **file structure** is:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── recognizer
│   ├── build
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── gradle
│   ├── gradlew
│   ├── gradlew.bat
│   ├── settings.gradle
│   └── src
```

So, I need to connect to `localhost` during `build` stage. It works. if I build Docker image with option `--network=host`, like that:

```
docker build --network=host -t recognizer .
```

But I don't know, how to specify build option for docker-compose.

Comment: Which build option are you looking for? Please clarify a bit.

Comment: @vivekyad4v ```--network=host ```

Comment: @vivekyad4v In `docker-compose bundle` reference it says that only images with "build option" will be exported. Question stands, "what is a build option" and "how do you specify it".

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to set network in docker-compose.yml like this:

```
build:
  context: ./
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  network: host
```

Then `docker-compose build your-service` will use host network for build stage.
This solved the problem for me